# http://localhost:xxxx/api/values could not load page in .net core 2.2

Tags: .net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, https

I am working with WebApi using .net core 2.2. If I access the API with URL https://localhost:44352/api/values, it works fine. But if I changed to use http://localhost:44352/api/values, using HTTP instead of HTTPS, it could not load.

This is Configure in Startup.cs

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseSwagger();
        //app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
        //{
        //    x.SwaggerEndpoint(@"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Api v1");
        //    x.RoutePrefix = "api";

        //});

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because of `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, you are setting your pipeline to redirect each HTTP call to HTTPS.

So first of all, remove this line.

Then, remove `app.UseHsts();`. You do not need to force SSL if you don't want to use HTTPS.

Now, you should be able to call your API using HTTP calls.

Comment: @ Skrface. Thank you. It worked. It seems I misunderstood the debug project setting. The port for HTTP and HTTPS are different but I used the same port while testing.